# Which API is used as a industry standard to generate pdf generation word document

Tags: java, itext, apache-poi

Which API is used as a industry standard to generate pdf generation word document, can some one provide a sample code for the same
I tried with iText api to successfully generate pdf document,which API is used to generate word document doc and also with .docx?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727993/using-the-same-api-to-write-both-word-and-pdf-documents or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991030/word-document-creation-api-in-java

Comment: Also, possible duplicate of a host of other similar questions to the bottom right of your screen under the mysterious "Related" tag. Do take the time to check them out.

Comment: What kind of word document are you after, .doc or .docx?

Comment: Could this question be asking what api word uses to generate pdfs?

Answer (score 3):

There is no such Industry Standard.